# What software allows drawing on PDFs?

Tags: pdf, software-rec

I need to be able to display a PDF in front of an audience and add annotations to it with the mouse, such as underlining parts and drawing arrows, with different available colors.

I've tried just projecting the PDF against a whiteboard, then annotating on the whiteboard, but when I need to move to the next page, I must erase the annotations.

What software is good for adding simple drawings to a PDF?

Comment: I recommend a pen on physical slides on an overhead projector. Reliable, easy to use, no installation necessary.

Comment: We don't have that at my workplace.

Comment: From my experience, xournal has often been unreliable. How about xournalpp (I do not have any first-hand experience with it)?

Answer (score 1):

[LibreOffice Draw](https://www.libreoffice.org/discover/draw/) can read in a PDF, and then overlay it with graphical objects.  Documentation is found at https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Documentation/Publications#LibreOffice_Draw_Guide and a quick review is at https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/tr-dojo/edit-pdf-documents-with-libreoffice-draw/

Since you are working with layers, if you want,, you can prepare a presentation in advance, save each phase in a separate layer, and rewind to just the initial layer before starting the presentation; then, as you step through the presentation, add layers back in. You can also preserve layers you made spontaneously during the presentation for future use. Handy.